# background-image, linear-gradient repeating, not expanding to the whole window

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have set the background image to a linear gradient but it repeats vs expanding to the full length of the browser window. I added the following prop/code to the `html` selector `height: 100%` and it fixes the problem. Why is this prop needed to make this work? I would like to understand what's going on.

This jsfiddle is an example https://jsfiddle.net/k0cdeu4x/ , not sure why there's a white bg on the paragraph element

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        html {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(176,194,213), white 700px);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p style="height: 700px">Foo</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/b4xtwvzk/1/

Comment: @doğukan you are coding in an iframe, if you try it on your local machine you will get the results I'm getting

Comment: I tried and got the same result